# Set form field value before is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having a bit of trouble grasping how to do this. I've put my best effort into searching Google without any luck.

I'll start with a bit of code and explain what I'm trying to do as I go:

## models.py

```
class Action(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='actions')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', editable=False)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', editable=False)

class ActionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Action
```

## views.py

By default, there is a dropdown field for owner. I have an icon that allows the user to enter a new username in a text field instead for owner. I check to see if `owner_new` was submitted and if so, create that user. I then need to set the `owner` field to that value so that `form.is_valid()` will be true.

```
def action_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionForm(request.POST)
        # check if new user should be created
        if 'owner_new' in request.POST:
            # check if user already exists
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('owner_new'))
            if not user:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST.get('owner_new'))
            # HERE IS WHERE I'M STUMPED
            form.owner = user.id
        if form.is_valid(): # THIS FAILS BECAUSE form.owner ISN'T SET
            action = form.save(commit=False)
            action.created_by = request.user
            action.modified_by = request.user
            action.save()
            return redirect('action_register:index')
    else:
        form = ActionForm()
    return render(request, 'actions/create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: May be worth a look at the accepted answer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517366/change-form-values-after-submit-button-pressed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def action_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionForm(request.POST)
        # check if new user should be created
        if 'owner_new' in request.POST:
            # check if user already exists
            user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(username=request.POST.get('owner_new'))                

            updated_data = request.POST.copy()
            updated_data.update({'owner': user}) 
            form = MyForm(data=updated_data) 

        if form.is_valid(): # THIS FAILS BECAUSE form.owner ISN'T SET
            action = form.save(commit=False)
            action.created_by = request.user
            action.modified_by = request.user
            action.save()
            return redirect('action_register:index')
    else:
        form = ActionForm()
    return render(request, 'actions/create.html', {'form': form})
```

A cleaner way of doing this is:

add `required=False` to the `owner` field.
Now,

```
if form.is_valid(): # THIS DOES NOT FAIL EVEN IF form.owner ISN'T SET
    action = form.save(commit=False)
    if 'owner_new' in request.POST:
        user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(username=request.POST.get('owner_new'))                
        action.owner = user
    action.created_by = request.user
    action.modified_by = request.user
    action.save()
    return redirect('action_register:index')
```

Comment: First, thanks for showing the `get_or_create()` function. I didn't know that existed. Second, I get an the error `This QueryDict instance is immutable` for `form.data['owner'] = user`, which is the problem I've been running into this whole time. Django just really doesn't want me messing with the values.

Comment: Yes it was, thank you very much for your help. One minor change is that `updated_data.update('owner', 'user')` must be called as `updated_data.update(owner=user)`.

Answer (score 1):

I came into a similar situation and couldn't figure out how to do it the way I wanted. What I ended up with was putting a link to a `UserForm` which allows a user to create a new `owner`, and then redirect back to the `ActionForm` with the argument `initial={owner: new_owner}` included when instantiating the form.