# change a form value before validation in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form and on my view function I do this :

```
search_packages_form = SearchPackagesForm( data = request.POST )
```

I would like to overwrite a form field called price which is decleared as such :

```
price = forms.ChoiceField( choices = PRICE_CHOICES, required = False,widget = forms.RadioSelect )
```

I would like to overwrite the form field before calling `search_packages_form.is_valid()`

I thought of doing :

```
search_packages_form.data['price'] = NEW_PRICE
```

But it does not work. Any ideas ?

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304148/set-form-field-value-before-is-valid maybe one of the solutions there can help.

Answer (score 13):

Probably not the Django way but based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17304350/2730032 I'm guessing the easiest way to change your form value before validation is to do something like the following:

```
def search_packages_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        updated_request = request.POST.copy()
        updated_request.update({'price': NEW_PRICE})
        search_packages_form = SearchPackagesForm(updated_request)
        if search_packages_form.is_valid():
             # You're all good
```

This works but I'd be interested if anyone has another way that seems more in line with Django, or if there isn't: then an explanation about why.

Comment: You should pass ```updated_request``` to the form instead of ```request.POST```.

Comment: @SirbitoX of course, I edited the answer. I'm not sure how I managed to make that mistake, thank you for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is build on an earlier proposal. It is a working solution, which can be used in several cases.

@Milad Khodabandehloo
had a tricky solution to solve the problem.

```
changed_data = dict(request.POST)
changed_data['price'] = NEW_PRICE
search_packages_form = SearchPackagesForm(data = changed_data)
```

as @The EasyLearn Academy commented: it does not allow you to access actual data submitted in form.

This is because the request.POST is immutable.

But there is a solution to the problem - just have to be more tricky.

This solution is only good if a reference to the object is enough for the certain cause. It leaves the object itself the same.

```
# write object to variable (data)
data = request.POST

# set to mutable
data._mutable = True

# modify the values in data 
data[modified_field] = new_value

# set mutable flag back (optional)
data._mutable = False
```

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

one trick for what you want is to do it like this:

```
changed_data = dict(request.POST)
changed_data['price'] = NEW_PRICE
search_packages_form = SearchPackagesForm(data = changed_data)
```

Comment: it does not allow you to access actual data submitted in form.

Answer (score 0):

`form.is_valid()` runs through your form's (and model's in case of a `ModelForm`) `clean` method's, returning `True` or `False`

If you plan on changing form data you can do it within the general clean method or at field level, e.g.

```
class YourForm(DerivingClass):
    # regular stuff

    def clean_<ATTR>(self):
        # here
        return self.cleaned_data

    def clean(self):
        # or here
        return super(YourForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: Not good for me. I cant do this. It must run before the validation and cant happen in the clean function. I basicily want to change the data came from the user.

Comment: I think you'll need to do that with javascript, then. Either `.change` or `.keyup`