# firing js before submitting remote bootstrap modal rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a rails4 app. I'm trying to do remote submission with the inbuilt AJAX mechanism (respond_to format.js and create.js.erb), but before I submit the form I want to change the code a bit via js to save the proper UTC time to db.

Everything works fine till the last line, so default behavior is pervented, time is properly formatted with momentjs, but the form doesn't get submitted in the end. Is something wrong with this `$('#new-task-modal-form').submit();` line? What else could I miss here?

form

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @task], remote: true, id: "new-task-modal-form") do |f| %>
....
....
<%= f.submit "Create Task", class: 'btn btn-primary new-task-submit', "data-sid" => current_user.id, "data-rip" => :executor_id %>
```

js

```
var ready = function() {

  $('.new-task-submit').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var localMoment = moment($('.new-task-deadline').val());
    $('.new-task-deadline').val(localMoment.toISOString());
    $('#new-task-modal-form').submit();
  });

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

I tried it this way as well, so momentjs can't be the problem:

```
var ready = function() {

  $('.new-task-submit').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#new-task-modal-form').submit();
  });

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Comment: did you try .on('submit'    then a function running your code and returning true (not preventing default)

Comment: lonewarrior556, can you plz show me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bootstrap modal issue. It's weird but I had to call the submit function on the modal not on the rails form: `$('#newtask').submit();`.

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @task], remote: true, class: "new-task-modal-form") do |f| %>
<div class="modal fade" id="newtask" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('.new-task-submit').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var localMoment = moment($('.new-task-deadline').val());
    $('.new-task-deadline').val(localMoment.toISOString());
    this.submit();
  });
```

Credit to lonesomeday https://stackoverflow.com/a/4517383/2898941

Comment: In this case form gets submitted, but JS doesn't get run. :(

Comment: I need something before create action because of rails. So something like on click, then preventdeafult + changing JS, and only then submit the form.